# Servo commands based on serial port input

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, device-driver

Straight to the point: Can you give me pointers on how to make this code more maintainable? In the future, I want to add more more things to this, but first it should be easy to maintain/read. Should making a library be considered?

What it does:

Takes input from the serial line and converts it to servo commands + all the bells and whistles added.

```
#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>


#define errorLED 13
#define ThrottlePin 2
#define RollPin 3
#define PitchPin 5
#define YawPin 4
#define Aux1Pin 6
#define Trigger 18
#define Echo 19
#define HEADING_PIN 15

NewPing sonar(Trigger, Echo);
Servo Throttle;
Servo Roll;
Servo Pitch;
Servo Yaw;
Servo Aux1;
unsigned int throttle = DEFAULT_THROTTLE;
unsigned int roll = DEFAULT_ROLL;
unsigned int pitch = DEFAULT_PITCH;
unsigned int yaw = DEFAULT_YAW;
unsigned int aux1 = DEFAULT_AUX1;
unsigned int temp = 0;
unsigned int range = 7;

unsigned long lastSerialData = 0;
unsigned long lastThrottleUpdate = 0;
unsigned long ledPreviousMillis = 0;

const int DEFAULT_THROTTLE = 45;
const int DEFAULT_ROLL = 70;
const int DEFAULT_PITCH = 70;
const int DEFAULT_YAW = 70;
const int DEFAULT_AUX1 = 45;

boolean isLedOn = false;
//Pins 7-12 power
//A0-A3 pin 13-16
boolean index = 7;
boolean circleIndex = 14;
void setup()
{
    Throttle.attach(ThrottlePin);
    Roll.attach(RollPin);
    Pitch.attach(PitchPin);
    Yaw.attach(YawPin);
    Aux1.attach(Aux1Pin);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    for (byte x = 7; x <= 12; x++)
    pinMode(x, OUTPUT);
    for (byte xy = 14; xy <= 17; xy++)
    pinMode(xy, OUTPUT);

    setPowerPinsOn(false);
    setGroundPinsOn(true);

    pinMode(errorLED, OUTPUT);

}

int GetFromSerial()
{
    // wait until we have some serial data
    while (Serial.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - lastSerialData > 1000) {
        digitalWrite(errorLED, HIGH);
        readSonar();
        blinkingLed();
        autoLand();
    }
    }

    lastSerialData = millis();
    digitalWrite(errorLED, LOW);

    return Serial.read();
}

void loop()
{
    switch (GetFromSerial()) {
    case 't':
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    if (temp >= 45 && temp <= 141)
        throttle = temp;    //45 to 141
    Throttle.write(throttle);
    break;
    case 'r':
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    if (temp >= 45 && temp <= 141)
        roll = map(temp, 45, 141, 69, 117); //45 to 141
    if (roll < (93 + range) && roll > (93 - range))
        roll = 93;

    Roll.write(roll);
    break;
    case 'p':
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    if (temp >= 45 && temp <= 141)
        pitch = map(temp, 45, 141, 69, 117);    //45 to 141
    if (pitch < (93 + range) && pitch > (93 - range))
        pitch = 93;
    Pitch.write(pitch);
    break;
    case 'y':
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    if (temp >= 45 && temp <= 141)
        yaw = map(temp, 45, 141, 68, 117);  //45 to 141
    Yaw.write(yaw);
    break;
    case 'a':
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    if (temp >= 45 && temp <= 141)
        aux1 = temp;    //45 to 141
    Aux1.write(aux1);
    break;
    }               // end switch
    if (throttle <= 45)     //Connected but not flying
    circleLed();
    else if (throttle >= 45 && aux1 > 45)
    headingLed();
}

void autoLand()
{
    if (throttle <= 60 && aux1 >= 50) {
    throttle = 45;
    aux1 = 45;
    } else if (throttle >= 45)
    if (millis() - lastThrottleUpdate > 400) {
        throttle = throttle * .95;
        aux1 = 45;
        lastThrottleUpdate = millis();
    }
    writeAllValues();
}

void writeAllValues()
{
    Throttle.write(throttle);
    Roll.write(roll);
    Pitch.write(pitch);
    Yaw.write(yaw);
    Aux1.write(aux1);
}

void setPowerPinsOn(boolean on)
{
    if (on) {
    for (byte x = 7; x <= 12; x++)
        digitalWrite(x, HIGH);
    } else
    for (byte x = 7; x <= 12; x++)
        digitalWrite(x, LOW);
}

void setGroundPinsOn(boolean on)
{
    if (on) {
    for (byte x = 14; x <= 17; x++)
        digitalWrite(x, LOW);
    } else
    for (byte x = 14; x <= 17; x++)
        digitalWrite(x, HIGH);
}

void circleLed()
{
    if (millis() - ledPreviousMillis > 400) {
    if (circleIndex == 18)
        circleIndex = 14;

    ledPreviousMillis = millis();
    setPowerPinsOn(true);
    setGroundPinsOn(false);
    digitalWrite(circleIndex, LOW);
    circleIndex++;
    }
}

void blinkingLed()
{
    if (millis() - ledPreviousMillis > 1000) {
    ledPreviousMillis = millis();
    isLedOn = !isLedOn;
    setPowerPinsOn(isLedOn);
    setGroundPinsOn(true);
    }
}

void headingLed()
{
    if (millis() - ledPreviousMillis > 300 - (throttle - 45) * 2) {
    ledPreviousMillis = millis();
    if (index == 13)
        index = 7;

    setPowerPinsOn(false);
    setGroundPinsOn(false);
    digitalWrite(HEADING_PIN, LOW);
    digitalWrite(index, HIGH);
    index++;
    }
}

void readSonar()
{
    int uS = sonar.ping_median();
    Serial.println(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);
}
```

Summary:
How can this code be more maintainable?
Should making a library be considered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start by breaking the code down into different files. There are a many `#define` and `const int` here. If I am correct that will definitely grow with your project. Having all the constants in a different file is always a good idea if you are considering making it even moderately big. So to your question

> Should making a library be considered?

I would say you should definitely make a library.

After that I'll go and indent this code properly. I couldn't understand where the `loop()` function started and where it ended in the first go. If you want readability that is a something that you must seriously consider. All of your functions need proper indentation but for the `loop()` function it is a must.

There is a lot of redundancy in your `loop()` function.

- The first 2 lines of each of your `case` is same. That is really bad programming. It made your code so big that you had to write comments to note down the end of your braces.
- You are writing same comments over and over again with no actual use. If you needed to change these you'll be getting a headache.

I'll write your `loop()` function something like this

```
#define TEMP_RANGE(x,y) (temp >= x && temp <= y)
#define CHECK_RANGE(x, y, z) ((y + z) > x && x > (y - z))

void loop()
{
    temp = 0;
    temp = GetFromSerial() + 45;
    switch (GetFromSerial()) 
    {
        case 't':
            if (TEMP_RANGE(45,141))
                throttle = temp;
            Throttle.write(throttle);
            break;
        case 'r':
            if (TEMP_RANGE(45,141))
                roll = map(temp, 45, 141, 69, 117);
            if (CHECK_RANGE(roll, 93, range))
                roll = 93;
            Roll.write(roll);
            break;
        case 'p':
            if (TEMP_RANGE(45,141))
                pitch = map(temp, 45, 141, 69, 117);
            if (CHECK_RANGE(pitch, 93, range))
                pitch = 93;
            Pitch.write(pitch);
            break;
        case 'y':
            if (TEMP_RANGE(45,141))
                yaw = map(temp, 45, 141, 68, 117);
            Yaw.write(yaw);
            break;
        case 'a':
            if (TEMP_RANGE(45,141))
                aux1 = temp;
            Aux1.write(aux1);
            break;
    }

    if (throttle <= 45) //Connected but not flying
        circleLed();
    else if (aux1 > 45)
        headingLed();
}
```

Note these

- I placed the range checks which were being done more than once into their own `define`. This made them much easier to read and change. You can make better names based on the context. I didn't use functions but you can use them for even better abstraction and readability.
- Due to proper indentation people will be able to read this much faster. That is very important if you want maintainability.
- Took out redundancy from your code. You were checking whether a number was `<= 45` something and in the `else if` you were checking whether it was `>=`. Obviously it is `> 45` otherwise the fist condition would have executed.
- It can be improve more if you use functions or a bit more little complex macros. Functions might be preferable.

I think I covered the biggest issues.

- Use a proper indentation in your whole code. That is essential.
- Maybe add function prototypes at the top to make it easier to find what is where.
- If you are thinking of making it big try to break it down into logical parts first.
- Use braces consistently. Sometimes you are using braces for containing single statements but sometimes you are not. That is a source of many bugs.

Hope this helped.
If you want more feedback I suggest you to fix these problems and ask another question with the updated code for more feedback.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :)